# Linear Search - Matching integer with list

Tags: python, linear-search

Hi am new to python here is what am trying to do , i have this below list.

```
x= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and here is my python code:

```
length = len(x)
c = input("Enter a no\n")

for i in range (length):
    if  x[i] == c:
        print ("Found at position ", i)
    else:
        print("not found")
```

and the output am receiving.

```
Enter a no
2
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
```

Now with my very few little knowledge what i figured out is this multiple not found is happening because every time loop takes a no checks with the list and if its not available its moving to else part due to lack no proper  `beak` statement **but what am not able to figure out that when it takes to in x[i]** its matching then output should be   `Found at position  1` . i read somewhere need to use `if c in x[i]` but it didn't work. on the hand i re-wrote the code.

```
def ls():
    t = int(input("Enter your search no \n"))
    for i in x:
        if i!= t:
            continue
        print("Your value is present in ")

        break
    else:
        print ("parrrrrrrrrrr")

ls()
```

which is working all good. It will be of help if i can get to know:

- with 1st program why its showing not found even the input is present in the list
- the part where *c in x[i]* was entered same issue happened as per my knowing *(which now makes no-sense)* it should also work
- if it is the case of integer vs list then how my 2nd code is working 
  -is it the rigt way to do linear search.

Comment: The problem is that you try to compare `str()` with `int()`. Liner search has O(n), but if your list is sorted, you can use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) with O(log n).

Comment: wtf: i forgot that input takes a string , thanks a lot and is there any link that can explain the o(n) details. Thanks @VadymStupakov

Comment: just type in google `big o notation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Because input returns you a `str` object and then compared with `int` object without implicit conversion, so the expression always be `False`.
2. `c in x` where x is a list works, but `x[i]` is an integer in your case
3. 2nd code is working because you convert the input into `int` implicitly

The most elegant way in my opinion is:

```
c = input("Enter a no\n")
items = [1,2,3]
print(items.index(int(c)) if int(c) in items else 'Not found')
```

And of course dont forget to catch ValueError if input is not convertable into integer

Comment: @SubhaSaha, I've updated my answer with more datailed explanation,

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and mentioning the point of value error, i recently  went through the concept of error handling. def thankyou():  @OlegRybalchenko :}

Comment: @SubhaSaha, you are welcome:) And please, mark it as answer if there are no more problems)

Comment: sure,no issues :)